# Adding Salt n Pepper noise into an Image manually

Tags: image-processing, matlab, noise

When i looked in to the algorithm of Salt n Pepper noise in a Matlab i've found this,

```
case 'salt & pepper' % Salt & pepper noise
    b = a;
    x = rand(sizeA);
    d = find(x < p3/2);
    b(d) = 0; % Minimum value
    d = find(x >= p3/2 & x < p3);
    b(d) = 1; % Maximum (saturated) value
```

Which i simplified as this,

```
% [a, code, classIn, classChanged, p3, p4]
% p3 = density
% p4 = variance
% a = Image
% code = noise Type 
% classIn = Image Class i.e unit8 , unit16, double
```

**% -------- ALGORITHM ----------%**

```
%     b = a;   <-- Assign b to the input image
%     x = rand(sizeA); <--- Generate random pixels from the image pixels
%     d = find(x < p3/2); <--- Find the pixels whose values are less than half of the mean value  
%     b(d) = 0 <-- Implement minimum noise to them
%     d = find(x >= p3/2 & x < p3) <--- Find the pixels whose values are
%                                        greater than half of the mean
%                                        value & less than mean value
%     b(d) = 1;     <-- Implement maximum noise to them
```

instead of using imnoise, I am trying to add Salt n Pepper noise manually into the image using the above algorithm,

```
I = imread('2.jpg');
J = rgb2gray(I);
p3=0.05 %default
b = J;
x = rand(size(b));
d = find(x < p3/2);
b(d) = 0; % Minimum value
d = find(x >= p3/2 & x < p3);
b(d) = 1; % Maximum (saturated) value
```

I don't know where the final image is stored as when i use imshow for b it show a simple image without salt n pepper noise.
Where the final image is stored ? how can i see the it ?

P.S: What does it mean by image class ? that is unit8 , unit16 ?

Comment: b(d) = 255; % Maximum (saturated) value
This worked for me .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the final image is in the variable "b". Observe that the max (salt) and min (pepper) values are respectively 1 and 0. This indicates that your original image needs to be an intensity image with graylevels normalized to [0,1]. This may be the reason why you don't see a sensible result when you display "b" as an image.

In case your image is grayscale {0,...,255} i.e. 8-bit unsigned integer format (unit8), you can change your code to assign 0 and 255 instead of 0 and 1.

I suggest you read the documentation on various image storage types here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html

It can get pretty confusing at times, mainly because there are so many names (intensity image, grayscale image, RGB, HSV, binary image, indexed image, etc.)